# glGetIntegerv / glGetFloatv Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am currently porting a game using the NDK. I am using native OpenGL, and am having problems using the glGet* functions.

Here is a code snippet:

```
m_camera.SetViewMatrix(); //just to make sure nothings left from the last render

        int viewport[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

        float proj[16];
        glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);

        float model[16];
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);

        m_currentRay.Create(x, y, 0.0f, 1.0f, model, proj, viewport);
```

Everything looks ok, but it seems like the glGet* functions are simply not working, and are not returning any values.

I have even tried initialising the variables to certain values, but when the glGet* functions are called, the variables are unchanged. For example:

```
int viewport[4];
viewport[0] = 1;
viewport[1] = 2;
viewport[2] = 3;
viewport[3] = 4;
```

and when glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport); is called, viewport is still the same. The same applies to all the variables.

A few notes:

- I am debugging on a HTC Wildfire
- Using GLES 1.0
- Android SDK version 2.2 (API version 8)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For getting matrices, check if your device has the GL_OES_matrix_get extension

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think that is for GLES 1.1, starting to think that glGetIntegerv / glGetFloatv are both for GLES 1.1 aswell, and Wildfire only supports 1.0.

Comment: I think that's exactly it; some Android devices support only a very old version of GLES. My reading of GL_OES_matrix_get is that it's about being able to get a floating point matrix back on versions of ES 1.1 that supply only the fixed point interface, but I guess if it were implemented on top of ES 1.0 then it'd solve the problem nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the wildfire uses the PixelFlinger software GL implementation. I know for a fact that PixelFlinger 1.2 does not implement glGetFloat, but have no information if later versions have corrected this. Is there any logging info when you call make the call? On 1.2 at least, there's a non-specific "unimplemented function" warning.

As to a solution - you'll just have to create the matrices in your own code and then upload them to GL.